# NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'CoordinateTransformation_TransformPoint'

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, latitude-longitude, landsat-8

Hello I am new to working with GeoTiff data and I am trying to grab lat/lon values from a tiff image. Here is my code:

```
import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import osr

# open the dataset and get the geo transform matrix
ds = gdal.Open(r'C:\Users\_______\Documents\Landsat8\LC08_L1GT_156120_20170207_20170216_01_T2_B5.tif') 
xoffset, px_w, rot1, yoffset, rot2, px_h = ds.GetGeoTransform()

x = 100
y = 100

# supposing x and y are your pixel coordinate this 
# is how to get the coordinate in space.
posX = px_w * x + rot1 * y + xoffset
posY = rot2 * x + px_h * y + yoffset

# shift to the center of the pixel
posX += px_w / 2.0
posY += px_h / 2.0

# get CRS from dataset 
crs = osr.SpatialReference()
crs.ImportFromWkt(ds.GetProjectionRef())
# create lat/long crs with WGS84 datum
crsGeo = osr.SpatialReference()
crsGeo.ImportFromEPSG(4326) # 4326 is the EPSG id of lat/long crs 
t = osr.CoordinateTransformation(crs, crsGeo)
(lat, long, z) = t.TransformPoint(posX, posY)
```

However, when I run this I keep receiving the following error:

```
NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded 
function 'CoordinateTransformation_TransformPoint'.
Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow::TransformPoint(double [3])
OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow::TransformPoint(double [4])
OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow::TransformPoint(double [3],double,double,double)
OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow::TransformPoint(double [4],double,double,double,double)
```

I have no idea what this means, I have looked up the error and found no useful information so I am hoping one of you have experienced this problem before.

Comment: Just a guess, but I can't see where the Z coord should come from when the input is XY. Any luck with `(lat, long) = t.TransformPoint(posX, posY)`?

Comment: Please include the *full* exception text, not just the last error message when asking questions on GIS-SE.  You may not have your `GDAL_DATA` env var set.

Comment: Here is the full error: NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'CoordinateTransformation_TransformPoint'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow::TransformPoint(double [3])
    OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow::TransformPoint(double [4])
    OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow::TransformPoint(double [3],double,double,double)
    OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow::TransformPoint(double [4],double,double,double,double)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the x/y variables were of type `numpy.float32` (read out of an array) which caused this exact error. Changing the types to regular `float` worked.

Answer (score 2):

This error is extremely confusing, but it is thrown when the in- or output projection is not set. Check your `crs` and `crsGeo` to check if they are not an empty.

If so, try updating `pyproj`, setting your `PROJ_LIB` correctly etc.

Comment: This helped me solve my problem, which was I had specified a very specific transformation using `osr.CoordinateTransformationOptions.SetOperation` that was inapplicable to the source/target CRS.